# Reason for different results for mfcc extraction using different libraries

Tags: audio, signal-processing, mfcc, librosa, tarsosdsp

I found two libraries (**librosa** and **tarsosDSP**), which are meant for audio signal processing. They both have a method to extract mfcc.

After running a simple example on the same `.wav` file they give quite different results:

[image]

Blue comes from librosa, orange from tarsosDSP. with `y=x  * -3/5` the orange line is almost exactly as the blue one.

What is the reason they are so different? I used exactly the example code, so I think the reason not that I call them with different inputs, but how they compute the results internally.